# Re-rendering React Components X times?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, for-loop

Shortly, my code imports a txt-file (via Webpack plugin), split each line by a special character to become usable by an Array.
The "Fixture" then calls a value from the array (e.g. `fixture = array[i]` when `i = 1`).
I then use that data in a substring function to get the data I need.
If `fixture = array[1]`, it would return for example Brentford as `homeTeam` and Arsenal as `awayTeam`.
Some of the data are `homeTeam` and `awayTeam`,

So, back to my React component, I need to re-render my component at least 10 times, but with different values on `i` (mentioned earlier as variable to `array[i]`).

As of now, my `return()`-statement of my main component returns a child component:

```
<Match hometeam={homeTeam} awayteam={awayTeam}/>
```

which send the `homeTeam` and `awayTeam` props to the child component.

I need to run `<Match/>` for X times with different values each time. How should I do it? Hope you can help me...

Comment: Do you mean you want to show one Match for each pair of home/away teams? And a fixture is one of these pairs? I’m not really sure exactly what your data look like here.

Comment: Yes, you are 100% correct, Chris. I have 2 variables: homeTeam and awayTeam. "Brentford" and "Arsenal". Those are both strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You typically do this by using `map()` to render a component for every item. To do this for each combination of two array, just nest one `map()` inside another.

For example:

```
<div>
  {homeTeams.map(homeTeam => (
    awayTeams.map(awayTeam => (
      <Match homeTeam={homeTeam} awayTeam={awayTeam} />
    )
  )}
</div>
```

Note how you don't typically need to know the index to do this, you just loop over every item in the array and render something with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to map your `array` to a list of `<Match/>`

```js
<div>
   {array.map(fixture => {
       let { homeTeam, awayTeam } = yourSubstringMethod(fixture);
       return (
           <Match homeTeam={homeTeam} awayTeam={awayTeam} />
       );
   })}
</div>
```

If you want to map part of your `array`, replacing `array.map` with `array.slice(0, 10).map`